# Fast way to find closest date from a list and apply to column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, datetime, sapply

I have a column with dates (A) and a column with list of dates (B). 
Here's how the input's format :

```
+------+------------+--------------------------------------+
| Idx  |    date    | list_of_dates                        |
+------+------------+--------------------------------------+
| 1    | 2015-01-07 |'2014-11-06','2015-08-05','2017-01-07'| 
| 2    | 2016-02-13 |'2013-11-07','2015-12-05','2017-01-07'| 
| 3    | 2013-11-08 |'2012-04-09','2014-02-15','2016-04-03'|
+------+------------+--------------------------------------+
```

I want to apply a function to this dataframe to produce a third column called `closest_date` where I would find the closest date (in the future) in `list_of_dates` to the date in `date`. For the example above, the output would be :

```
    +------+------------+--------------------------------------+-------------+
    | Idx  |    date    | list_of_dates                        |closest_date |
    +------+------------+--------------------------------------+-------------+
    | 1    | 2015-01-07 |'2014-11-06','2015-08-05','2017-01-07'| 2015-08-05  |
    | 2    | 2016-02-13 |'2013-11-07','2015-12-05','2017-01-07'| 2017-01-05  |
    | 3    | 2013-11-08 |'2012-04-09','2014-02-15','2016-04-03'| 2014-02-15  |
    +------+------------+--------------------------------------+-------------+
```

I was able to write a function that takes a date and list of dates and return the closest  then used `sapply` to produce then column but it's extremely slow.

Anyone has an efficient approach to do this ?
Thanks.

Comment: Please follow the posting instructions at the top of the [tag:r] tag page and in particular show the input in reproducible form and also show the corresponding output.

Comment: Try: `lapply(seq_len(nrow(x)), function(i) {j <- x$B[[i]] > x$A[i]; x$B[[i]][j][which.min((x$B[[i]] - x$A[i])[j])]})` with data: `x <- data.frame(A=as.Date("2015-01-07"), B=I(list(as.Date(c('2012-04-07','2014-11-06','2015-08-05','2017-01-07')))))`

Comment: you might want to check out the rolling join from `data.table`